# How to fill SAP form with additional IP address bought (2 sub domains) and RMM setup

Tags: marketing-cloud, sender-authentication-package

we have bought a SAP package and an additional dedicated IP to manage our commercial (email.company.com) and transactional (support.company.com) sends separately with 2 different sub domain as mentioned. Can someone explain how the additional IP is setup? Do I need to fill the SAP form twice? Currently we have added transactional IP setup details in comments of our SAP form.

Also how will the RMM work for this, If we want to keep RMM switched off for transactional emails.

Comment: Please clarify exactly what you purchased: If you bought one SAP, that gives you _one_ subdomain to delegate and _one dedicated IP_. - Question: Did you buy that SAP _plus a private domain_, _plus an additional IP_ ? - if so, good. Or did you just buy the SAP but have the above requirements (less good).

Comment: Hi @JonasLamberty we bought one SAP and additional dedicated IP (not private domain) . Here is what the AE sent me - 

What was provided in the package was to cover any eventual requirements.

- Two additional BUs, one for region A, one for region 2.
- Two SAPs each with their own Dedicated IP
- Two additional Dedicated IPs in case the client wanted to separate transaction and promotional sending.

Comment: right, so you have two SAPs. Good - OK I will write up an answer.

Comment: edited my answer - added clarification that if you want to use two sendout subdomains _from within the same BU_ your two SAPs don't help, you need an additional private domain.

Comment: Thanks a lot @JonasLamberty, this makes it very clear to me. I am also having a call with SF Solution Engineer, if there are any other updates apart from things mentioned by you, I will add it as a comment below. Cheers!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For each BU you can deploy one SAP.
For each SAP you have, you fill in a separate form.

Last time I checked, the SAP form asks nothing about Dedicated IP.
The standard procedure here is, one Dedicated IP will be set up automatically with the SAP, for the BU whose form you fill out.

That is UNLESS you specify in a remark that you want something specific about the setup with that one IP. (e.g. you specifically do not want to have a dedicated IP but stay on a shared pool).

So - each SAP form deploys one dedicated IP pretty much "automatically" unless you object.

Now you want a second IP in the same BU, and have a dedicated IP purchased:
Open a separate support ticket. The way to alter anything about IP setup is through a support ticket, I believe in the Deliverability subsection.

The standard behavior after a second IP deployed is that the default "delivery profile" rotates the two, but you can specify that other delivery profiles use either IP exclusively and assign them for e.g. transactional vs. commercial send classifications.

There is relatively high flexibility with Dedicated IP setup also post-deployment, like, you could make two BUs use the same IP etc. - all through support.

===

To be clear:

Sending from two separate subdomains in the same BU is not possible unless you purchase an additional Private Domain for sending.

Private Domain doesn't cover all SAP features (when it comes to branding), but can be set up in the same BU as an existing SAP and gives you another sendout domain to choose from.

With just two SAPs and no private domain purchased, you *have* to split your two subdomains to separate BUs. This is notably NOT as flexible as the IP stuff. One BU - one SAP  is a hard rule.

===

RMM settings are done inside the BU as a fallback, and you can override the default setting by Sender Profiles. So this is completely unconnected to the IP setup or the SAP form.  Simply defining and using separate Sender Profiles for commercial / transactional should cover your requirement.

I would recommend researching the docs at https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.mc_es_reply_mail_management.htm&type=5 first.

If you need specific details then I would open another question to keep some focus.